# Let $x$ be an integer and let $d$ be a factor of $2x^2 − 1$. Prove that $d^2 ≡ 1\bmod 16$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratics

So I tried expanding and got $d^2$ to be $4x^4-4x^2+1$. From what I think, I believe that I have to prove that $4x^4-4x^2 ≡ 0\mod 16$, but I have no idea on how I can do that and my approach could be wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $d$ is a factor *of* $2x^2-1$, that doesn't mean it *is equal to* $2x^2 -1$.  Your expansion equating $d^2 = 4x^4-4x^2 +1$ assumes $d =  2x^2-1$.  That's not what the title states.

Comment: prime $p$ is a factor of $2x^2-1\iff 2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ $\iff p\equiv\pm1\bmod 8;$ if $d$ is a product of primes $\equiv\pm1\bmod8,$ then $d\equiv\pm1\bmod8$, which is equivalent to $ d^2\equiv1\bmod16$

Comment: This was also posted, in some form here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361903/number-theory-integers

Answer (score 1):

If $d$ is a factor of $2x^2-1$, then any prime factor $p$ of $d$ is a factor of $2x^2-1$.

Prime $p>2$ is a factor of $2x^2-1\iff 2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$

$\iff p\equiv\pm1\bmod 8.$  Obviously $2$ is not a factor of $2x^2-1$.

So $d$ is a factor of $2x^2-1\iff d\equiv\pm1\bmod8
\iff d^2\equiv1\bmod16$.

The last equivalence follows because if $8|d\pm1$ then $16|(d+1)(d-1)=d^2-1$.